# django-angular example error

Tags: python, django, angular, django-angular

We hope this thread will help users running the django-angular package for Python.

At the moment, we are following the example: [django-angular](http://django-angular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

We are able to get the demo running, but have an error loading some of the static files. The creator of the package is saying this is related to Django, and not the package its self, even though we are running the example "out of the box" without making changes.

Here is the error:
[image]

And what we see:
[image]

The example should look like this: [working example](https://django-angular.awesto.com/combined_validation/)

What we have tried:
At the moment, all dependencies including angular have been installed. We're thinking maybe something isn't mapped correctly in the `urls.py` file. Any advice would be appreciated, and hopefully this thread will help others using this package.

Comment: It looks like it is an issue with the css. Did you try to debug it on chrome with developer tools?

Comment: Do u have set `STATIC` folder in Django settings?